# Using Xpath Not

Tags: xpath

I have the following that I am generating in an Xpath query:

```
<xforms:instance id="Instance">
      {//xforms:instance[@id="Instance"][ .= "Code" ]}
      <Code>blah</Code>
</xforms:instance>
```

As it is it will return where the tag is 'Code' in the instance block. However, I want it to return everything else, and not 'Code'

I have tried variations including:

```
[ .not(="Code") ]}
[ .!= "Code" ]}
```

But these don't seem to work. I'd be grateful for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the things you have tried "don't seem to work". In what context? What software do you use? How can I do what you are doing?

Comment: `.not(= "Code")` is not valid XPath - did you mean to write `not(. = "Code")`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the text node?

`/xforms:instance/text()`